# Yii2-dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I'm working in Yii2 dynamic form, but I need to add little function to add, sub and multiply 2 fields and put value in a third. I written some code but I couldn't call the function on textfield.

How to call the functions in field?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function earnings() 
{
    var bs = document.getElementById('basic_salary').value;
    var da = document.getElementById('dra').value;
    var ta = document.getElementById('tra').value;
    var gs = parseInt(bs) + parseInt(da) + parseInt('ta');
    if (!isNaN(gs)) 
    {
        document.getElementById('gross_salary').value = gs;
    }
 }
 function deduct()
 {
     var lv = document.getElementById('leave').value;
    var pd = document.getElementById('per_day').value;
    var ra = parseInt(lv) * parseInt(pd);
    if (!isNaN(ra)) 
    {
        document.getElementById('reduced_amount').value = result;
    }
 }
 function net()
 {
    var gs = document.getElementById('gross_salary').value;
    var ra = document.getElementById('reduced_amount').value;
    var ns = parseInt(gs) - parseInt(ra);
    if (!isNaN(ns))
    {
        document.getElementById('net_salary').value = ns;
    }
 }
</script>
```

```html
<h4 class="box-title text-aqua"><?php echo Yii::t('payroll', 'Earnings'); ?></h4>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'basic_salary')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
             'placeholder' =>$model->getAttributeLabel('basic_salary')], ['id'=>'basicSalary']) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'dra')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('dra')], ['id'=>'dearnessAllowance']) ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'tra')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
        'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('tra')], ['id'=>'travelAllowance']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'gross_salary')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('gross_salary')], ['id'=>'grossSalary']) ?>
        </div>
</div>

<h4 class="box-title text-aqua"><?php echo Yii::t('payroll', 'Deduction'); ?></h4>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'leave')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('leave')]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'per_day')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('per_day')]) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'reduced_amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('reduced_amount')]) ?>
    </div>

<h4 class="box-title text-aqua"><?php echo Yii::t('payroll', 'Total Amount'); ?></h4>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'net_salary')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('net_salary')]) ?>
</div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying your code in a test environment, I noticed several problems.  ActiveField->textInput, for instance, takes only one argument (the array of html attributes) - see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#textInput()-detail.  Also, if you fix that as in the example below, you will have an input with an id "basicSalary"; your javascript earnings function is looking for "basic_salary" and won't find it.  There are numerous other mistakes of this type.

I suggest you:

- Open the yii2 documentation and keep it open while writing your code
- Use your browser's development tools to inspect html and debug javascript (e.g. in Chrome use "Inspect" to view the generated html code, and the Sources tab to view, set breakpoints, etc. in your javascript)
- Invest some time reading about [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/); it will make your life much easier.

(Original, corrected answer:) You can add the onchange property to each field; the function you specify will be called each time the user types something.  For example,

```html
<?= $form->field($model, 'basic_salary')->textInput([
             'maxlength' => 30, 
             'placeholder' =>$model->getAttributeLabel('basic_salary')],
             'id'=>'basicSalary',
             'onchange' => 'earnings()',
         ]) ?>
```

To match the code above, your earnings() function needs to start with:

```javascript
var bs = document.getElementById('basicSalary').value;
```

Comment: It's not working sir.please have a look sir                                              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                     <?= $form->field($model, 'basic_salary')->textInput(['maxlength' => 30, 
                             'placeholder' =>$model->getAttributeLabel('basic_salary')], 
                             [
                                'id'=>'basicSalary',
                                'onchange' => 'earnings()',
                             ]) ?>
        </div>